# Misunderstanding While loop

Tags: unix, while-loop

Having trouble getting this to exit the loop and perhaps I don't understand the while loop well enough to get it to stop.  This is what I'm typing in my command line.  I expect it to stop at 10.

```
 c=1; while : [[$c -le 10]]; do df -Th; echo "$c";  date; c=`expr $((c+=1))`; sleep 6; done
```

I've already read article but it didn't seem to help: [bash while loop won't stop itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575497/bash-while-loop-wont-stop-itself)

Final code:

```
c=1; while [[ $c -le 10 ]]; do df -Th; echo "$c";  date; c=$((c+=1)); sleep 6; done
```

The final code required removing the `:` and adding  between the `[[$c` and `10]]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin

Comment: I sort of knew this, but it seemed every example included the colon.  It was an interesting read though.

Comment: The call to `expr` is unnecessary; the arithmetic expansion does all the work. If `c` is currently 2, then the expression reduces to `c=$(expr 3)`, then `c=3`. but `c` was already set to 3 by the `+=` operator. All you really need is `((c+=1))`.

Comment: I had that originally, but read the post I shared in original post.  FWIW, there were two reasons for my code not working, the colon and the lack of spaces.  I do not believe the post you linked to is the full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, spaces are important.  Replace:

```
: [[$c -le 10]]
```

With

```
[[ $c -le 10 ]]
```

#### What went wrong

When bash encounters

```
: [[$c -le 10]]
```

it executes the command `:` with three arguments, `[[$c`,  `-le`, and `10]]`.  This is not what you want.  First, `:` is the no-op command: regardless of its arguments, it does nothing.  Second, if you want to run the `[[` test command, it needs, as shown above, spaces around it.

#### Alternatives

There are several ways to loop something 10 times in bash.  For one:

```
$ for c in {1..10}; do echo "$c"; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

For another:

```
$ for ((c=1;c<=10;c++)); do echo "$c"; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized spaces were important with bash.